# How to differentiate gesture and click?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to implement logic for panning surface and be able to click on it to place image, but when I'm trying to add gesture detector as simple as:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

And when I'm starting gesture, image being placed on screen. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check here:

[Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

Comment: Yes, thankyou, it help. I just missed that thing that click event is followed by gesture if I'm returning false as a gesture result.

Comment: Interesting thing, that setOnClickListener() is required even if there's no logic in it (I've moved all logic to onSingleTapUp()

Answer (score 1):

Use the classes and interfaces from android.gesture, especially OnGestureListener. The OS takes of care of recognizing gestures.

Answer (score 1):

As Hyperboreus said, use the `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` interface which you associate to your `GestureDetector` instance. No need then to associate a click listener to your view *and* a touch listener. Specifically, use the `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent)` method for detecting clicks, the `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.onFling(MotionEvent, MotionEvent, float, float)` method for detecting flings, and so on and so forth.

Remember to return `true` in your implementation of the `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.onDown(MotionEvent)` method.